# Howto store a project in a large wxpython application

Tags: python, wxpython

I am developing a rather large python application (wxpython) that allows a workflow of data analysis. Performing all steps of the workflow can be quite long and the user is not likely to everything at once. More likely he would prefer to do different parts of the processing at different points in time. It would therefore be very handy to be able to store the application's current status with some sort of "save project" functionality. Opening the application and loading a project file would set up the application as it was previously and allow one to continue where he/she left off last time.

However I have a large amount of objects to save, most of which are imbued with attributes coming from wxpython. This causes pickle to fail with the following error:
TypeError: can't pickle PySwigObject objects

Does anyone has experience with this? What would be a best practice to obtain the required functionality? Are there libraries devoted to this?

Thanks you.

Comment: Would it be possible to store only some raw data and then recreate the `wx` interface according to the loaded data? Like just a list of preferences or currently shown widgets.

Comment: That was indeed the only thing I could come up with. But it seems very labour intensive, so I was kind of hoping there were more efficient solutions. But I guess this will be the way I will have to do it in the end...

Comment: I'd think you really care about saving the state of the process (what has been done in the analysis) not much about the GUI (you can save the preferences but that's all I'd care about). If your application has "save" and "load" functionality you could use that. And, if it doesn't perhaps it's a good idea to add it. That's how I do it anyway.

Comment: You will need to separate your objects from wxPython. One of the core rules of GUI development is to separate out the tasks that run the interface from the tasks that process data etc. You can then pickle your data and load it arbitrarily from wxPython apps or any other script you choose to create.

Comment: Thank you all. Following your advice I got something that works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

wxPython is a wrapper around a C++ library known as wxWidgets. So you cannot use normal Python serialization to save its state. However, you can use the persist library to save most widget's state: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.persist.html

I'm not sure when this library was added to wxPython, but I'm guessing it was with 2.9 or perhaps the latest version of 2.8. Otherwise you can probably find it in the latest version of 2.8's source.

As others have said, it's usually better to just save the process's state and then load that information back to the GUI when it's started.